# Why would $this->getFormKey() fail silently in $APPHOME/downloader/template/login.phtml?

Tags: magento-1.9, error, magento-connect, downloader, magento-connect-manager

I'm having an issue in *$APPHOME/downloader/template/login.phtml* where `<?php echo $this->getFormKey() ?>` is failing silently, and the rest of the page is refusing to render.  Of course this is making it impossible to log in to the **Magento Connect Manager**, which is where I need to be adding an extension or two.

Here's a screenshot of the broken **Connection Manager** login page:
[image: Broken Connect Manager Admin Login]

Of course this isn't too helpful without where the code is broken:
[image]

As is indicated in the source view, the value tag in first (hidden) input method attempts to parse *$this->getFormKey()*, evidently, and fails, halting rendering of the rest of the page.

I'll admit that I'm still a bit mystified where it comes to the magic getters/setters in Magento.  I've worked on tracing down where this code may lay, and the closest I've gotten so far is *$APPHOME/downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php* at line 106, in the `authenticate()` method.

If anybody has any ideas why this may be happening, how to fix it, or where I might go for more information (other than just the general magic getters/setters page, which I'm still re-reading over and over), I would be very appreciative.  Any pointers are helpful.

Comment: Most probably there is a fatal error somewhere on the line, and you don't see it because you have error reporting off, or you have display errors off. Turn them on and you should see the error message.

Comment: Any idea where the applicable options that I would change for that may be located in the admin page?  I'm having some difficulty locating the applicable logging options; it looks like _syslog-2.log_, and _connector_api.log_, are updating just fine, yet not showing me anything about this issue.  Portions of the applicable logs are showing that these ones are updating at a debugging level.  System->configuration->advanced->developer shows that logging is set to 'yes' and to log to _syslog-2.log_.

Comment: It looks like this may have something to do with addition of the _SUPEE-6285_ security patch.  Anybody else had any similar problems?

Answer (score 0):

`getFormKey` is not a magic getter, it's a method in [`Maged_View`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/4bc632edf76c1008b7dccde3e5c7357ce2c00087/downloader/Maged/View.php#L161), which delegates to [`Maged_Controller`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/053e0b286cbd6d52ac69ca9fd53a3b72c78aca1d/downloader/Maged/Controller.php#L1136), which delegates to [`Maged_Model_Session`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/053e0b286cbd6d52ac69ca9fd53a3b72c78aca1d/downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php#L230).

The SUPEE-6285 patch, mentioned in the comments above, added additional form keys in the connect manager, but the `getFormKey` methods were there before, so it's not an issue of incomplete patches.

Enable error reporting to see the PHP fatal error with the exact line where it fails and check the code there. More on the topic: [Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store)